# bash error when launching jupyter notebook - bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

When I try to launch Jupyter Notebook I get this error:

```
$ jupyter notebook
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I want it to use python 3.7 (located below), which I have downloaded, not python 3.9.

```
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin
```

Why is Jupyter trying to open with 3.9, which doesn't exist? How can I get it to use 3.7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied from:

https://allenfrostline.com/blog/bad-interpreter-error-jupyter/

> It turns out that the cause was that along with reinstallation of
> Python, the homebrew symlinks to Jupyter are now broken. A simple
> solution would be

```
rm '/usr/local/bin/jupyter'
brew install jupyter
brew link --overwrite jupyter
brew link --overwrite --dry-run jupyter
brew unlink jupyter && brew link jupyter
```